# Output Data From Two Tables With Identical Columns And Add Variable As Identifier

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

Lets say I have two tables, with identical column names, and when I want to output them into a table, I simply want an additional field to show the user which table it came from...
i.e.

#### Table1

```
---------------------------------------------------
ID| name | address | another_identifier|  color
-------------------------------------------------
1 | Bob  | 123 Nowhere | 12345         |  gray
2 | Jane | 321 nowhere | 54321         |  red
3 | Jack | 555 somewhere | 12993       |  blue
```

#### Table2

```
------------------------------------------------
ID| name | address | another_identifier|  color
------------------------------------------------
1 | Bob  | 123 Nowhere | 12345         | purple
2 | Jane | 321 nowhere | 54321         | green
3 | Jack | 555 somewhere | 12993       | blue
```

#### Query

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.* FROM table1 a, table2 b";
$results = $class->runQuery($query); // basically a fetchAll to create an array
```

#### Display Code

```
foreach($results as $row){          
$html .= "<tr>";
//Now print the name            
$html .= "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
// Print the address
$html .= "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";

//NOW PRINT WHAT TABLE ITS FROM
if (table == "table1")
    $html .= "<td>Its from Table 1</td>";
else if (table == "table2")
    $html .= "<td>Its From Table 2</td>";

$html .= "</tr>";
        }
print $html;
```

#### Side Notes

1) Please do not assume both tables contain identical information... there is an omitted column for example purposes

2) In order to assist in not asking another question... can you please also answer:  How can I modify my original `$query` to not display the rows which have, i.e. identical `name` columns.

3) However, the original question still stands... I must display ALL rows regardless if there is a match or not....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could have 2 queries instead of 1 and just combine the results using PHP or you could use the SQL UNION command, but that would force you to have the same columns and types in both tables. Either way, from a design standpoint, your solution doesn't seem like a good one.

Comment: Your query is going to creat a full cross-product between the two tables, since there's no `WHERE` clause to filter the results. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Barmar its more for example purposes...the `where` is the least of my problems lmao

Comment: But it's fundamental to understanding what you're trying to do. Your query will join the two tables side by side, is that what you want? Or do you want them merged row by row like fthiella's answer?

Comment: @Barmar Essentially I would prefer to output the data into rows, sorted by name... there is an omitted column, and I will modify my question now to show it... but I must know which table its from

Comment: Question 2 - you want to not display the duplicates at all, or just display them once instead of twice?

Comment: @Barmar Question 2 shouldve been left out lol...its only adding confusion to this current question lol. It was more for reference purposes to another 'issue' i had.  Don't even worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I would use a UNION query like this:

```
SELECT 'table1' As table_name, table1.*
FROM   table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'table2' As table_name, table2.*
FROM   table2
```

This will select all rows from table1 and all rows from table2, and the name of the table where records come from.

Both tables need to have the same structure, otherwise you need to specify the column names:

```
SELECT 'table1' As table_name, table1.ID, table1.name,
       table1.address, table1.another_identifier
FROM   table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'table2' As table_name, table2.ID, table2.name,
       table2.address, table2.another_identifier
FROM   table2
```

To answer your second question, you could use this query to return your records only once:

```
SELECT MIN(table_name), ID, name, address, another_identifier
FROM (
  SELECT 'table1' As table_name, table1.ID, table1.name,
         table1.address, table1.another_identifier
  FROM   table1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'table2' As table_name, table2.ID, table2.name,
         table2.address, table2.another_identifier
  FROM   table2) s
GROUP BY
  ID, name, address, another_identifier
```

(and it will return table1 in case records are present in both of them).

Or maybe you need to use this:

```
SELECT 'table1' As table_name, table1.*
FROM   table1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE table2.name=table1.name)

UNION ALL

SELECT 'table2' As table_name, table2.*
FROM   table2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE table1.name=table2.name)
```

that returns only rows that are present in one table but not in the other.

Comment: You can't use `table1.*` and `table2.*` if the tables don't have equivalent columns in the same order. Both subqueries have to have the same number of columns and the types have to match.

Comment: Okay, if this is the case for the query... How would I modify my if statement to print the correct name....obviously I didn't set a variable to do so in the question...  But I think THIS MIGHT work perfectly for me

Comment: @Barmar both tables have exact names & types...just different and/or same data entered (the omitted one will ALWAYS be different)

Comment: Your first answer to #2 has two problems: no GROUP BY, and it won't necessarily show the data from the table that it names with `MIN(table_name)`.

Comment: @hawkhorrow $row['table_name'] will contain the name of the table where the rows comes from

Comment: @FTHIELLA friggin awesome!  Thank you all for your help!  +1

Comment: @Barmar i forgot the group by, thanks, edited my question. Yes I am not grouping by name but by all columns, it might be correct or it might be not, but it depends on the OP intentions...

Answer (score 1):

fthiella has answered question 3. Question 2 can be solved using GROUP BY:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 'table1' As table_name, table1.*
      FROM   table1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT 'table2' As table_name, table2.*
      FROM   table2) x
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

When there's a duplicate name, this will pick one of them arbitrarily.

Comment: but how would I modify my actual output statement to show which table it was from... (and whats the x for?  is that needed?)

Comment: The `table_name` column says which table it was from. And the `x` is because subqueries are required to have an alias even if you don't use it.